# How can I determine if this is a context connection file missing or a cookie

Tags: c#, sql, file, exception, model-view-controller

I am not able to successfully debug an issue to determine the cause. This is happening sporadically to users. I can sometimes fix the issue by clearing browser history. I am not able to reproduce the error myself via localhost so debugging has been an issue. Any pointers from the stack trace would be helpful.

Thanks.

```
The system cannot find the file specified

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   ECOM_2015.<>c.<ConfigureAuth>b__0_1(CookieExceptionContext context) +13
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +3455
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +49
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1008
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +483
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +653
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +653
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +653
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +291
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +293
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +208
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +443
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

[Screen Print after user tries to access page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBZNk.png)

Comment: Please add the error as text instead of a image link, links tend to decay faster then you think and having the error as text makes it searchable and it can be used in a possible answer.

Comment: Thanks.. I added the error text.